# Using MS USB Keyboard and Mouse becomes erratic

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, dock, usb-hub

When I have the USB plugged directly into the laptop I have never had a problem but I wish to plug it into a USB C dock.

When I do it works fine some time, hours,  and may become erratic, i.e. unable to type consistently or get erratic mouse movement. Move the USB back to the laptop and everything works fine.

Comment: There would appear to be a problem with the Dock. Is it new enough to get a warranty replacement?

Comment: @John The dock is brand new and I've had problems with other USB hubs also. For example, I have a  Seagate drive that has two USB 3.0 ports. If i plug the USB it gets the same results.

Comment: It still seems like the dock because multiple devices fail in the dock. I would contact the vendor of the dock.

Comment: Not sure if I misled but everything but the mouse / kb work.

Comment: Thanks. Try a different mouse / keyboard combination to see if the issue is unique to the mouse / keyboard you currently have

Comment: Tried my spouses and it did the same thing.

Comment: If it works in the computer and not in the dock or hub, there must be a compatibility issue there